# Paypal AJAX combination

Tags: ajax, paypal

I'm developing an online shop for non-digital goods completely in AJAX. Is there any chance to have a Paypal checkout without having to leave the current page? I've found a way to use a lightbox, but as far as it seems to me you can just use it for digital goods.

Is there any other way to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How would a user know that they were entering their credentials into PayPal and not your website if they didn't see "www.paypal.com" in the URL bar? A proper authorization flow really should navigate to the identity provider and then redirect back after entering login credentials there.

Comment: Thank you for the response. You are right, but I want to use the shop as a Phonegap Build application, too. I could find a way with a redirect for the online version, but that won't work within Phonegap Build. (Sorry for not mentioning Phonegap in the original post.)

Answer (score 0):

The other option you have out there is PayPal Payments Advanced, Layout C, which allows you to further customize the payment page that is embedded in an iFrame on your website.

Below is a reference to another question on stack that referenced buyers staying on the seller's website:

[Stack Question with PayPal Advanced Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243089/how-can-a-buyer-without-being-redirected-to-paypal-complete-the-transaction/23256532#23256532)

Here is the PayPal Payments Advanced Integration Guide:
[PayPal Payments Advanced Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/)